# Cursor not runing thru whole table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Okay, i got this cursor and it needs to update column test with the result from @sql query.
but it doesnt update each column with their own result from query, like he doesnt execute that query for each column, if u undestand me.

```
declare @promenjiva nvarchar(max)
declare @docidgodina nvarchar(max)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @var int
declare @var1 int

declare c1 cursor for

select documentid,a4 from damdocumenttype1 order by documentid--a inner join dbo.Delovodnik b on a.documentid=b.idinstance

begin
open c1;

fetch next from c1 into @var,@promenjiva
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
set @promenjiva=REPLACE(@promenjiva,'C','')
SET @SQL = 'select stuff((
            SELECT '', '' + a1
            FROM DamDocumentType1
            where documentid in (' + @promenjiva + ')
            FOR XML path('''')
            ), 1, 2, '''')'
exec @docidgodina=sp_executesql @sql
update dbo.Delovodnik set test=@docidgodina

fetch next from c1 into @var,@promenjiva

end

end
close c1
deallocate c1
```

I can join someTable with damdocumenttype1 on documentid, just so you know

Comment: Why are you intentionally creating a delimited list of values like this? You should use a normalized structure instead of cramming values into a single tuple. It will make things more difficult for you in the long run. All the gyrations you have to go through to create the data you will have to undo every single time you want to query it.

Comment: This is just one time cursor and its my first curosor i dont know a lot about them, so I need a code, I cant understand much by reading you comment :D

Comment: What you are doing is stuffing a comma delimited list into the column test. This violates 1NF when you multiple values in a single cell (called a tuple in DB world).

Answer (score 0):

When you do your update statement:

```
SET @SQL = --some sql query...
update someTable set test=@sql

fetch next from c1 into @var,@promenjiva
```

You don't use a where clause. So you update the whole table. I suspect you want:

```
UPDATE  SomeTable
SET     Test = @sql
WHERE   DocumentID = @Var;
```

You almost certainly don't need a cursor here though. If you post your full code, someone should be able to rewrite this in a set based manner, which will perform much better.

---

**ADDENDUM**

The following should achieve the same result without the need for loops:

```
UPDATE  d
SET     Test = STUFF(dt.docidgodina.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM    dbo.Delovodnik AS d
        CROSS APPLY 
        (   SELECT  CONCAT(',', a1)
            FROM    dbo.DamDocumentType1 AS dt
            WHERE   CONCAT(',', REPLACE(d.a4, 'C', ''), ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,' + dt.DocumentID + ',%')
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ) AS dt (docidgodina);
```